# Sources on Educational intervention changing consumer preferences?

Tags: reference-request, behavioral-economics, education-economics

I'm doing some research on how education can change a consumers preference for a given good or service. Im looking for more research papers or books that discuss such a topic.

I've looked around online a little bit and read 
[The Effects of Consumer Education on Consumer Product Safety Behavior](http://www.acrwebsite.org/volumes/9384/volumes/v04/NA-04) by  Richard Staelin, however I'm looking for more sources on the topic.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It will be easier to search for education changing decisions/outcomes, rather than `preferences' as within most economics literature those don't change.

Answer (score 1):

I found research on this topic from the recent October 2016 issue of the American Economic Journal: Applied Economics. However I could not find the PDF online from the site however I got it from a different source.

Titled as
[The Impact of High School Financial Education: Evidence from a Large-Scale Evaluation in Brazil](http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/753501468015879809/pdf/WPS6723.pdf) it is learned that its possible to change consumers habits via curriculum design.

> *We find significant treatment effects on spending behavior as well. In line with the concepts
>   taught in the curriculum, the results show a 2.1-2.5 percentage point greater likelihood of
>   comparison shopping before making purchases, and a 3.1-4.1 percentage point greater likelihood
>   of negotiating price or payment method prior to purchases by students in treated schools. Further,
>   the results show that 16 percent of students in treated schools made a list of monthly expenses as
>   part of a budgeting exercise compared to 13 percent in the control schools in follow-up 1. These
>   numbers are 17 percent and 14 percent respectively, in follow-up 2. **All treatment effects are
>   statistically significant at the 1 percent level.***
>
> **Overall, these results show a clear improvement in student behavior as a result of the financial education course, in line with concepts taught in the curriculum.**

The article concludes

> Financial education in schools is an important policy focus in both developed and developing
>   countries, yet its impacts are not well understood. This paper contributes to the literature by
>   demonstrating that a financial education program targeted to youth in secondary school can
>   improve both knowledge and behavior, as well as influence financial attitudes and preferences.

Excellent research, and a recommended reading.